# Validate input password with underscore text in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to allow a password with first character with underscore like "_Abc1234", but it only allows me if underscore is before other character like "A_bc1234"

here is the input

```
<input
  matInput
  type="password"
  formControlName="inputPassword"
  autocomplete="off"
  [textMask]="{mask: validator, guide: false}"
/>
```

and the validator is:

```
this.validator = this.validateInputsNotSpace;
public validateInputsNotSpace(rawValue: string): RegExp[] {
    const mask = /[a-zA-Z0-9_@#¿?*-]/;
    const nameMask: RegExp[] = [];
    rawValue.split('').forEach(x => {
        nameMask.push(mask);
    });
    return nameMask;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not working? i tried the below regex and it is allowing the password "_Abc1234". try it out yourself in regexpal - https://www.regexpal.com/

/[a-zA-Z0-9_@#¿?*-]*/

Comment: its a question not a answer to the post writer. add it in comment.

Comment: Sure.. But, i  don't have enough reputation points to add a comment to the original post.